How to perform this jump in Doom Eternal?
I'm stuck at this jump. I already didn't complete the tutorial because the combination of double-jump, (double?) dash and E (whatever this stands for) is not really feasible to achieve before even getting to know the game. So, I started the campaign which also doesn't provide any noticeable support to get to know the controls. Or it's less complicated than I assume, there's however no way for me as a player to figure this out in the game.
So far I tried randomly guessing combinations of double jump, dash and E, fell about 40 times. Tried the tutorial again, failed the tutorial again. There's a walkthrough which shows that the jump is supposed to occur, yet I have no idea how to achieve it. And of course I'm on the lowest difficulty level.
I never had such a depressing start in a game, but I want to see if the game starts to be any fun at any point at all.


It really should be a matter of just doing a double jump after swinging on the yellow pipe.  You  will need to get the timing right, but that's about it.  There is actually a steam forum post about the tutorial as well as this exact jump being mentioned, maybe it can give you some insight https://steamcommunity.com/app/782330/discussions/0/2967272318179373229/

The secret, not mentioned in the tutorial, this video, this post and probably many more is that you need to hold jump to be able to do a double jump.
You must not stop pressing Space after jumping on the bar which catapults you further until you reach the maximum height or after and then you release Space and quickly after hit space again.
And if you do the same, but once released Space double jumping doesn't work - no idea why, it's a challenge to react quickly in a shooter, not to plan your jumps which you have to, in order to be able to double jump later.
I'm pretty sure that's it, I can't go back now because the only save the last checkpoint not all of them, so I have to restart the campaign.
